# Why am I getting protocol/SSL-errors on NPM install?

Tags: node.js, npm, protocols

I'm a newly hired employee trying to get NPM to work on the machine I just got from my company (Lenovo P15s with Windows 10). No matter what I try to fetch with NPM, I get the following error:

> request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: write EPROTO 10540000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:922:

NPM init works fine.

**What I've tried so far:**

- Checked proxysettings to see if I'm behind a proxy (I'm not, as far as I can see - the settings are all clear)
- Removed and reinstalled Nodejs and NPM several times, both through the Windows installer and through NVM/cli
- Running "NPM install" from Node version 19.4, 18 and 17 with correlated NPM-versions. Same error regardless
- Turning off strict-ssl (I'm aware of the risk, just tried for test purposes) - on Node v17+ I get the same error, but turning off strict-ssl on v16 gives me this error instead:

> errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain

- Testing on another clean machine from the company still gives me the EPROTO error
- Setting the NPM-registry with "npm config set registry [http://registry.npmjs.org/"](http://registry.npmjs.org/%22)
- Setting NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 (I know this is risky as well).

No luck.

I have read that you can set the path to a certificate-file in the config file, but walking down that whole certificate-road, I honestly have no idea what I'm doing. I downloaded a DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA-certificate and tried pointing the path to that, no change at all.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing or what I can do?

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing the same issue & so far no luck regarding the solution.

Comment: A common pattern which causes problems is that a lot of companies terminate and reencrypt SSL traffic with their own root certificate (man in the middle attack). If that's the case you will need to add your company root to the list of trusted certificates. You can verify this by running curl or openssl s_client against registry.npmjs.org and check what the root certificate is.